# NullPointerException with ArrayList - should not be possible?

Tags: java

Today I got a NullPointerException at a point where it actually can't occur.

```
Exception in thread "Timer-9" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at packagename.censored.Bot.changeServergroups(Bot.java:1363)
    at packagename.censored.Bot.xpTask(Bot.java:1239)
    at packagename.censored.Bot.access$7(Bot.java:1187)
    at packagename.censored.Bot$9.run(Bot.java:729)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
public void changeServergroups(int cldbid, ArrayList<Integer> addList, ArrayList<Integer> removeList) {
    // If there are groups to add AND delete, remove them from the lists
    if (addList != null && removeList != null) {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(addList);
        for (int s : temp) { // THIS IS LINE 1363
            if (removeList.contains(s)) {
                addList.remove((Integer) s);
                removeList.remove((Integer) s);
            }
        }
    }
    // some more code, to do the actual group changes
}
```

How is it possible to get the NullPointerException there? I check to make sure that `addList` is not null before creating a new temporary ArrayList from it. Can someone tell me how this could possibly return in a NullPointerException?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only possibility is that your list `temp` contains `null`. The null `Integer` is then unboxed to an `int` and that throws a NPE.

You can solve the NPE by using `for (Integer s : temp)` if having a null value is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I'll check if it is possible for `addList` to contain null at this point.

Comment: shouldn't unboxing of null to int throw NFE ?

Comment: This turns out to be the correct answer. Due to a bug in a different method `addList` here contained null, which resulted in the NPE as described. Thanks!

Comment: @SacJn Not sure what you mean by NFE. Try to run `for (int i : Arrays.<Integer> asList(null));` to see that it throws a NullPointerException.